# How to stop a thread whose run() doesnt have a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

How to stop a thread whose run() doesnt have a loop. 
So basically I want a replacement for the stop() method. 
I want to stop one of the Thread when there is a deadlock. 
I dont want to use locks. Just want to kill one thread so that the resource will be freed and other Thread will continue thus ending the program.

I tried still using stop() but even that is not stopping the program.

Following is my code:-

```
public class Deadlock {

    public static boolean stop = false;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            final String resource1 = "resource1";
            final String resource2 = "resource2";
            // t1 tries to lock resource1 then resource2
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                // Lock resource 1
                synchronized (resource1) {
                  System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");

                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      }

                  synchronized (resource2) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");
                  }
                }
              }
            };

            // t2 tries to lock resource2 then resource1
            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                synchronized (resource2) {
                  System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");

                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);

                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  }

                  synchronized (resource1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1");
                  }

                }
              }
            };

            // If all goes as planned, deadlock will occur,
            // and the program will never exit.
            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(t1.isAlive() && t2.isAlive())
            {
                System.out.println("Deadlock");
//              t1.stop(); Deprecated
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fix a bug other than by actually fixing the bug. If a thread has a bug, the bug has to be fixed or it will contaminate the process context.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908055/721269) for just one of the reasons it's not safe to reach into a thread from the outside and release its locks. Also, the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) in dst's comment is very helpful.

Comment: The same way you fix any bug. Understand how the code gets deadlocked and work out a sane fix. Maybe two locks are acquired in the wrong order. Maybe you can release one lock before acquiring the other. Maybe you can acquire a lock with a timeout and do something else if you can't get the lock. But you have to actually *find* and *fix* the *cause* of the deadlock. There's no magic dust that solves the problem without finding its cause.

Comment: I have intentionally created the deadlock. Just wanted to know if we can kill the Thread. But it seems that it cant be done that way. Both the links were helpful.